# Получить данные из формы

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, xhr

Здравствуйте. На сайте есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую генерируется хэш, который мне нужно получить. Этот хэш я могу посмотреть через дебаггер браузера, нажав на кнопку и посмотрев, какой я получаю response от сервера после этого.

Как это сделать автоматически? Т.е. как можно получить response после нажатия на кнопку программно?

Вот баттон в дебагере : [image: кнопка]

вот что получаю после нажатия на кнопку в дебагере браузера в разделе network : [image]

Comment: Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. **Приведите пример кода.**

Comment: Вам надо написать код который будет посылать ajax запрос на сервер и получать ответ. Покажите код вашей формы с кнопкой.

Answer (score 0):

Если просто нужно получить данные, можно попробовать `jquery`
`.submit` сабмитит форму, передает в переменную `data` и затем отправляем через json. Ответ с сервера отображаем в браузере через `console.log()`.
Чтобы работало у вас, нужно поменять на свои параметры эти два значения:
`/index.php`,`$("#form_id")`

```
            <script>
                $("document").ready(function() {
                    $("#form_id").submit(function(event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        data = $(this).serialize();
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: "json",
                            url: "/index.php",
                            data: data,
                            success: function(otvet) {
                                console.log(otvet);
                            }
                        });
                        return false;
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Файл `php`:

```
  function is_ajax() {
        return isset($_SERVER ['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER ['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
    }

    if(is_ajax()){
    // здесь обращаемся к $_POST['...']  чтобы извлечь данные из приехавшей формы
    echo json_encode(array('post'=>serialize($_POST))); // просто чтобы в браузере увидеть данные
//  echo json_encode(array('status'=>1)); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Найдите место, куда сохраняется этот хэш, назначьте ловушку-прокси на объект или `Observer` на DOM.
И получайте хэш.

Пример:

```js
let view = document.querySelector('#view'),
    data = {
      hash: ''
    };

document.querySelector('#getHash').addEventListener('click', _ => {
  // Допустим, здесь будет асинхронная операция на 0.5sec
  // Эмуляция запроса
  setTimeout(_ => {
    view.innerHTML = '76d80224611fc919a5d54f0ff9fba446'; // DOM
    data.hash = '76d80224611fc919a5d54f0ff9fba446';      // JS object
  }, 500);
});






// Отслеживаем изменения в DOM (вставку хэша в span#view)
new MutationObserver(ms => ms.forEach(m => useHash(m.target.innerHTML)))
    .observe(view, {childList: true});

// Отслеживание изменения JS объекта, куда сохраняют хэш
// Подменяем оригинальный объект на прокси с ловушкой на set
let _data = data;
data = new Proxy(_data, {
  set(target, key, value){
    if(key === 'hash')
      useHash(value);
    
    target[key] = value;
    return true;
  }
});

function useHash(hash){
  console.info(`Мы добыли хэш: ${hash}`);
}
```

```html
<input type='button' id='getHash' value='Получить хэш!' /><br />
Хэш: <span id='view'></span>
```